# Conditional logic with WordPress taxonomy in wp-admin area

Tags: wordpress, logic, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

Is it possible to add conditional logic to taxonomy in admin post area (I mean while creating new post)?
Like I have two taxonomies

1. Destinations with terms (a, b, c, d) and
2. services with terms (1, 2, 3, 4 etc)

How to show services taxonomy in post ***only*** if Destination is `a` or `c`?

Comment: And making `Destinations - A` a "parent category" isn't an option? It's not conditional logic, but it's rendered as a nested list in the admin.

Comment: @mevius, what if i want to show it if Destination is a or c ? i think parent category is not a good option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basic jQuery, you'll just need to study the DOM and define the relevant IDs or write a selector that matches your taxonomies.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', function() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#serviceschecklist li label input:checkbox').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#destinationchecklist li label input:checkbox').change(function() { 
            $checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            $val = $(this).val();
            switch( $val ) {
                case '8':
                    if( $checked ) {
                        $('#in-services-10').attr('checked',true);
                        $('#in-services-12').attr('checked',true);
                    } else {
                        $('#in-services-10').attr('checked',false);
                        $('#in-services-12').attr('checked',false);
                    }
                break;
                case '9':
                    if( $checked ) {
                        $('#in-services-11').attr('checked',true);
                        $('#in-services-13').attr('checked',true);
                    } else {
                        $('#in-services-11').attr('checked',false);
                        $('#in-services-13').attr('checked',false);
                    }
                break;
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
});
```